# How to check if record exists in any row at the selected column?

Tags: postgresql

I was looking for an answer, but I didn't find the right one I guess.

I have a table.
|login|password|e-mail|

I wanna know if entered login exists in 'login' column.

I have found answers where code is searching whole table.

Comment: Please tell us something about your data (example) and how the login you want to check is given. What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE login = (?) )
I guess its the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "case when" expresions in your SQL, like below:

```
select 
    case when login is not null then true else false end as is_login_existed 
from 
    your_table
```